# Корректно ли выражение "связь медитации и концентрации"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы

"5 исследований о связи медитации и концентрации." Или должно быть так: "... о связи медитации с концентрацией"? Склоняюсь ко второму...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Три варианта корректны: связь А и Б, связь А с Б, связь между А и Б.

Это подтверждается словарем и промерами из Нацкорпуса.

[Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C&all=x)

> СВЯЗЬ, -и, предл. о связи, в связи и в связи; ж. 1. Отношение взаимной
> зависимости, обусловленности. Прямая, косвенная, логическая, органическая, причинная с. С. фактов, явлений, событий. С. **между** промышленностью и сельским хозяйством. С. **науки и производства**. Хозяйственная с. районов. Творческая с. **художника с традициями** древнерусского искусства очевидна. Все гуманитарные науки находятся в тесной связи **друг с другом**

Но "связь с" скорее односторонняя. Не уверен, что Вам подходит. Если концентрация первична, то да, "связь медитации с концентрацией".

Замечание. Предложение не рекомендуется начинать с цифры.